# use Pi as internet gateway

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, raspberry-pi

I've got several devices connected to a Sky router (Sky Hub SR101) via wifi and Ethernet. 
I have a usb wifi dongle conected to my raspberry pi. And use it to connect to a 4G smartphone. (That works fine. I have access to the internet from the raspberry pi.)

What I wanted to know is if it is possible to keep all the devices connected to the sky router and share the 4G coming from the smartphone...through the raspberry pi that acts like the Gateway to the internet.
And if I get another device. I can easily connect it to the 4G network just by connecting it to the Sky router (instead of the smartphone directly).

**Note that the Sky router has no connection with the internet.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there shouldn't be  a problem. Just enable IP forwarding on your Pi and set it's IP address as default GW. Then you have to configure default route on Pi to be your WiFi dongle.

To enable IP forwarding edit */etc/sysctl.conf*:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Then to apply changes use:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Finaly, depends on distribution you have installed on Pi ( I assume Rasbian? ) use:

```
/etc/init.d/procps.sh restart
```

Reference: http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

EDIT: Oh, and don't forget you have to plug Pi into LAN port of Sky router.

Comment: That’s not enough, though. To completely replace a SOHO router, you’d want a DHCP server as well. Depending on what the smartphone can handle, `SNAT`/`MASQUERADE` may also be necessary.

Comment: @DanielB so something like this? 
http://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/

Comment: @Txugo Yes, although you want to share wireless to a wired network, not the other way around. That means you don’t want Hostapd.

Comment: Shouldn't the SNAT be done on smartphone? It already should do NAT if the Pi connection works and there is no reason to do NAT two times. Good point with DHCP, although it will work also from Sky router if you choose to.

I would consider also setting up some basic iptables filtering, I don't think smartphones really have stateful firewall.

Comment: The Sky router will always advertise itself as the default gateway, so DHCP clients won’t be able to connect to the Internet. Sure, the phone most likely does SNAT (which also implies SPI), but it might be limited in the number of client devices allowed.

Comment: It all depends on settings of capabilities of DHCP server of SOHO router. In most cases you can specify different gateway in DHCP server so that shouldn't be an issue. There is no rule that DHCP server must be on GW.

Comment: I haven’t seen any SOHO router where you could specify the gateway.

Comment: I've followed this tutorial://raspberrypihq.com/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-wifi-router/
but inverted (eth0 as wlan0 and vice versa).
installed and configured the ISC-DHCP-Server.
disabled my sky router's dhcp server. but I have no internet connectivity now.
I can connect to my sky router and get an IP given to me by the pi. I can ping my pi. I can ping google (and have connection to the internet) from within the pi.
There must be something wrong with my routing tables. Any ideas?
I've tried to setup my routing tables using that tutorial and set a static IP to the eth0 of the pi.